# is wordpress hosted in Github or anywhere in Git Repositories?

Tags: wordpress

I know wordpress is opensource cms, I want to know about ongoing changes , development phases in wordpress, is it hosted in Git repositories like Github , Bitbucket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress is hosted on GitHub too. It gets a push from SVN every 15 minutes.
[GitHub link](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress)

But if you want to contribute to create tickets you can do one in the [WordPress Track System](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/).
In the [Core blog](https://make.wordpress.org/core/) you will can find every information you need when they update something, even with notes for developers.